# How can I move the clear button in a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

For some reason, when I add a UITextfield as a subview of the contentview of a tablecell, the clearbutton does not align with the text typed in the field, and appears a bit underneath it. Is there any way I can move the text of the clearbutton to stop this from happening? Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen this, and a screen shot would be helpful. But, the quick answer is that you can inspect the subviews array of the UITextField, find the subview that contains the clear button, and adjust its frame.origin.

Edit: It seems I've been downvoted for this answer (written in 2010). This is of not an "officially" approved method because you're manipulating private objects, but it's not detectable by Apple. The main risk is that the view hierarchy might be changed at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm on the road right now but once I get to a stop, I'll try this out and update you.

Comment: Yeah im just going to move the subview.

Comment: The code of UITextField.m is not accessible. UITextField should be subclassed

Comment: @Luda, you downvoted me because you don't "like" my solution? Yeesh.

Comment: Yes,
You can't access the .m of UITextField. And further more, you should not access it. You can change exposed properties or subclass. But the provided solution is wrong.

Comment: It works. "Because apple doesn't want you to do it" is not a valid technical argument, it's a matter of opinion and whether you'll get caught.

Comment: If "apple doesn't want you to do it", then probably apple plans to change it in future. If you are okay with fixing stuff here and there for random sdk\iOS releases, then you can go this way. Otherwise, you should follow their guidelines

Answer (score 38):

As stated by @Luda the correct way is to subclass UITextField and override `- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds`. However the bounds passed in to the method are those of the view itself and not the button. Therefore you should call `super` to get the OS provided size (to avoid distortion of the image) and then adjust the origin to suit your needs.

e.g.

```
- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect originalRect = [super clearButtonRectForBounds:bounds];
    return CGRectOffset(originalRect, -10, 0); //shift the button 10 points to the left
}
```

Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/clearButtonRectForBounds%3a) state:

> **Discussion** You should not call this method directly. If you want to
>   place the clear button in a different location, you can override this
>   method and return the new rectangle. Your method should call the super
>   implementation and modify the returned rectangle’s origin only.
>   Changing the size of the clear button may cause unnecessary distortion
>   of the button image.

Answer (score 11):

The answer from Van Du Tran in Swift 4:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {


override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let originalRect = super.clearButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)

    return originalRect.offsetBy(dx: -8, dy: 0)
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4, 5**

> **Subclass UITextField (Working Perfectly, Tested)**

```
class textFieldWithCrossButtonAdjusted: UITextField {

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let originalRect = super.clearButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)

        //move 10 points left

        return originalRect.offsetBy(dx: -10, dy: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify a valid reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 4):

I had subclassed the `UITextField` and override the function `clearButtonRectForBounds:`.

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TVUITextFieldWithClearButton : UITextField

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "TVUITextFieldWithClearButton.h"

@implementation TVUITextFieldWithClearButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
}


- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.size.width/2-20 , bounds.origin.y-3, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```

Comment: It appears that you've downvoted the other answers. Not cool.

Comment: I down-voted one of the answers. I did it because the answer, in my opinion, is wrong. I have commented why I think so, and I will be glad to continue talking to you about that (on the relevant thread). Most importent is to understand how are things done right and not how cool are you.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UITextField and override this method:

```
- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x - 10, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}
```

return the CGRect that matches your needs.

Comment: This wont put the button in the right edge. This will: return CGRectMake(bounds.size.width/2-20 , bounds.origin.y-3, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version would be

```
import UIKit

class LoginTextField: UITextField {

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: xPos, y:yPos, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }

}
```