# UITextField "clearButtonRectForBounds" method not calling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I am creating a textfield with clear button mode using the following code.

```
  self.TextField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 200, 30)];
    self.TextField.tintColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.TextField.returnKeyType =UIReturnKeyGo;
    self.TextField.clearButtonMode =UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    self.TextField.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.TextField];

- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x - 10, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height+30);
}
```

I want to set custom frame for clear button, For that i am trying to call "clearButtonRectForBounds". But "clearButtonRectForBounds" method not calling. How can i set frame for clear button?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sub class `UITextField` and there need to overwrite `-(CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` method as described by @Luda in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870633/1603234

Comment: I have a UIViewController subclass.In that class i have a TextField

Comment: Okey, but you've to make a class which subclass of `UITextField` and then use in your `UIViewController`.